# Reference element values from array in XSL

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, parameters, rss

I am new to XSL and very confused about an issue.

I have an rss feed on SharePoint which comes through in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  -<rss version="2.0">-
<channel>
  <title>Company Name</title>
  <description>Company News and Events</description>
  <link>http://website.com/</link>
  <item>
    <title>Article</title>
      <description><p>Something</p></description>
      <pubDate> 12 Jan 2015</pubDate>
      <link>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/807</link>
      <guid>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/807</guid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Article</title>
      <description><p>Something</p></description>
      <pubDate> 20 Dec 2014</pubDate>
      <link>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/806</link>
      <guid>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/806</guid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Article</title>
      <description><p>Something</p></description>
      <pubDate> 13 Dec 2014</pubDate>
      <link>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/805</link>
      <guid>http://website.com/news-and-knowledge/news/805</guid>
  </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I have my RSS reader which generates a single large list, but I want to put breaks whenever there is a new month.  i.e. in the above example it would output:

> ```
>                                Jan 2015
> ```
>
> •Article Title Title title title
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                                  Dec 2014
> ```
>
> •Article Title Title title title
>
> •Article Title Title title title

My code which prints the date for EVERY record is below.  I just need a way to compare PrevPosition.pubDate with CurPosition.pubDate

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt"
           xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
           xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
           xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart">

<xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">30</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">true</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
<div>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rss/channel">
<xsl:variable name="link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="description" select="description"/>

<ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</ul>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_title" select="description"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$Rows"/>
<xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
<xsl:variable name="PrevPosition" select="position()-1" />
<xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
<xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0)">
  <div align="center">
    <hr/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(pubDate,3,9)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
<li>
  <a href="{$item_link}" title="{$item_title}">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
        <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </a>
</li>




</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
<xsl:param name="Html"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
    <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code is a mashing of something I found online and what I know to work from another feed I have running.   If only there is some way to say:

`when 
    CurPosition.substring(pubDate,3,9) <>= PrevPosition.substring(pubDate,3,9) 
         System.Out.Println(substring($pubDate,3,9))
  Else ()`

but unfortunately that is a combination of 3 languages and likely not syntactically correct!

Any help very appreciated

Comment: "*I want to put breaks whenever there is a new month.*" That's one way to look at it. Another way - IMHO, a better one - is to say you want to **group** the articles by month. In XSLT 1.0, this is done by a method known as Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

> If only there is some way to say:
>
> when CurPosition.substring(pubDate,3,9) <>=
>
> PrevPosition.substring(pubDate,3,9) >
>
> System.Out.Println(substring($pubDate,3,9)) Else ()

The equivalent in XSLT would be:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="substring(//pubDate[position()], 3, 9) != substring(//pubDate[position() - 1], 3, 9)">
    <hr/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise/>

</xsl:choose>

<xsl:value-of select="//pubDate"/>
```

**References**

- [XPath - Being Choosy with Predicates](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathpredicate.php)
- [Overview of XSLT and XPath: Predicates](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Offices/Presentations/XSLT_XPATH/28.html)
- [XML Information Set (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/)